# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to

Tags: java

I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to ...model.MyClassAttributes` exception at `for(MyClassAttributes mc : atList)` , even if I have done a cast to the entity.

```
List<MyClassAttributes> atList = new ArrayList<MyClassAttributes>();
atList=(List<MyClassAttributes>)session.createSQLQuery(SELECT_QR_SQL).setLong("rec", rec).list();
for(MyClassAttributes mc : atList)
{

}
```

When I checked the compiled class it seems cast didnt update.

```
atList = session.createSQLQuery("Select col from....").setLong("rec", rec.longValue()).list();
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: What does session.createSQLQuery return?

Comment: `select col1,col2 from some_table where col3=:some_val` - returns object list

Comment: Try casting it to a normal List without generics. It just returns a simple list. [Click here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.4.sp1/org/hibernate/Query.java#Query.list%28%29)

Comment: What's the point of assigning a `new ArrayList` if you immediately replace it by the result of the other call?

Comment: Yeah, that's redundant, but shouldn't be part of the actual problem. But of course, that initialization of the local variable should be removed for being pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not know any generics at runtime. This is called "type erasure". Since the `list()` method already returns a `List<A>`, typecasting it to some other `List<B>` (where `B` is a subclass of `A`) doesn't generate any additional bytecode.

Note how the `ClassCastException` occurs in the `for` loop, not the assignment. With the loop variable you (and also the compiler, since you casted before) assume that the `List` contains only `null` and `MyClassAttributes` objects, but apparently that isn't the case, since the exception is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this? 
Don't initialize the List object. Just declare it
eg -

```
List<MyClassAttributes> atList;
```

The reason the cast isn't working is - You have a `List` instance with an `ArrayList` Object in it. And the `sqlQuery<>.list()` function is returning a `List`.

Casts work only when the 'is-a' relationship is satisfied.

`ArrayList` is-a(always) `List`. So you can cast an `ArrayList` instance as a `List`. But the `List` may not be an `ArrayList` all the time. So the cast doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter what was assigned to the `atList` variable before assigning something else. Particularly the value of a variable doesn't affect any unrelated typecasting. The `ClassCastException` really tells that the list doesn't contain `MyClassAttributes` objects, at least not exclusively.